# Make tmux ignore the default configuration file

Tags: tmux

I have a default configuration for tmux at `~/.tmux.conf` but I'm wondering how to make tmux ignore it by passing specific commandline argument to it.

I looked around the manuals and the help command but don't think i saw anything about it. And I'm aware i could just rename or move/delete the configuration file, but i would prefer to just ignore it by using commandline argument provided by tmux instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring the default config file can be achieved by using the `-f` flag to specify the config file, and `/dev/null`:

```
tmux -f /dev/null
```